# Добавить условия в retainAll() и addAll в MutableList

Tags: android, list, kotlin

Я использую методы `addAll()` и `retainAll()`. И в сумме они отрабатывают хорошо. И всё же можно сделать так чтоб они не смотрели на первый параметр (boolean). Я бы не хотел чтоб он изменялся и влиял тут при сравнивание. Как этого можно добиться?

```
fun test(){
    val noteTypesCheck = mutableListOf<NoteType>()
    noteTypesCheck.add(NoteType(false,"hello", 1))
    noteTypesCheck.add(NoteType(false,"qwe", 2))
    noteTypesCheck.add(NoteType(true,"qwe", 3))
    noteTypesCheck.add(NoteType(true,"qwe", 5))

    val noteTypes = mutableListOf<NoteType>()
    noteTypes.add(NoteType(true,"zxc", 1))
    noteTypes.add(NoteType(true,"qwe", 2))
    noteTypes.add(NoteType(true,"bye", 4))

    updateNoteTypes(noteTypesCheck, noteTypes)
}
```

Сама функция

```
fun updateNoteTypes(noteTypesCheck: MutableList<NoteType>, noteTypes: MutableList<NoteType>): MutableList<NoteType> {

    noteTypesCheck.addAll(noteTypes)
    noteTypesCheck.retainAll(noteTypes)


    noteTypesCheck.forEach{
        Log.e("TEST", "${it.id} ${it.checkout} ${it.name}")
    }

    return noteTypesCheck
}
```

Приходит ответ

```
1 true zxc
2 true qwe
введите сюда код
```

Comment: `bye` нет в ответе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил его двумя способами(Разные коллекции)

**HashMap**

```
fun getNoteTypes(start: HashMap<Int, NoteTypeItem>, from: HashMap<Int, NoteTypeItem>): HashMap<Int, NoteTypeItem> {
    //Add and Update
    for (key in from.keys) {
        if (start.containsKey(key)) {
            if (start.getValue(key).name != from.getValue(key).name) {
                val startNote = start.getValue(key)
                startNote.name = from.getValue(key).name
                start.put(key, startNote)
            }
        } else {
            start.put(key, from.getValue(key))
        }
    }
    val result = hashMapOf<Int, NoteTypeItem>()
    //Delete
    for (keyStart in start.keys) {
        if (from.containsKey(keyStart)) {
            result.put(keyStart, start.getValue(keyStart))
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

**MutableList**

```
    fun getNoteTypes2(start: MutableList<NoteTypeItem>, from: MutableList<NoteTypeItem>): MutableList<NoteTypeItem> {
    //Add and Update
    var result2 = mutableListOf<NoteTypeItem>()

    for (keyFrom in from) {
        for (keyStart in start) {
            if (keyFrom.id == keyStart.id) {
                if (keyFrom.name != keyStart.name) {
                    val startNote = keyStart
                    startNote.name = keyFrom.name
                    result2.add(startNote)
                } else {
                    result2.add(keyStart)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (keyFrom in from) {
        var check = true
        for (keyResult in result2) {
            if (keyFrom.id == keyResult.id) {
                check = false
                break
            }
        }
        if (check) {
            result2.add(keyFrom)
        }
    }
    return result2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно переопределить метод `equals(Any?)` в классе `NoteType`:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    return (other as? NoteType)?.let { 
        this.id == it.id && this.name == it.name
    } ?: false
}
```

Comment: Я посмотрю ваш способ